# How to animate more fluently a rotation of a background gradient within element?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a button and I would like to animate its background by rotating it:

```css
.gradient-button {
  animation: rotate-gradient 1s infinite;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red, yellow, green);
}

@keyframes rotate-gradient {
  0% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red, yellow, green);
  }
  /* Adding a step in the middle */
  20% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, red, yellow, green);
  }
  40% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, red, yellow, green);
  }
  60% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, red, yellow, green);
  }
  80% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(240deg, red, yellow, green);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(300deg, red, yellow, green);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="fill" class="gradient-button">Fill Form</button>
```

However there are only 6 steps and animation is not fluent, adding 24 frames manually is counterproductive.

Alternatively I tried JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    AnimateRotate(360);
});


function AnimateRotate(d){
    var elem = $("#mybutton");

    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: d}, {
        duration: 2000,
        step: function(now){
            elem.css({
                 "background-image":"linear-gradient("+now+"deg, red, yellow, green);"
            });
        }
    });
}
```

but that does nothing.
Question: How to make this animation fluent?
Running code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OaojNP

Answer (score 11):

If it were me I'd probably take the illusion a different route since a linear gradient is going to be tough to do a smooth keyframe animation on without stepping it through each property change. Instead as an alternative approach perhaps a transform on a pseudo element could give the same desired result?

As such;

```css
.gradient-button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.gradient-button:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2rem; right: 0; bottom: -2rem; left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow, green);
  animation: rotate-gradient linear 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-gradient {
  to { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
```

```html
<button id="fill" class="gradient-button">Fill Form</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

`background-image` is not *animatable*. 
You could add an absolute positioned (pseudo-)element and use transform to rotate it, as long as you hide the overflow and make sure the limits are never visible.

But if you ***really*** want a rotating background (because it's cool, and you can), you could use an `<svg>` as background and SMIL animations to rotate the gradient direction:

```html
<svg width="240" height="60" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <animate attributeName="x1" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y1" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="x2" values="1;1;0;0;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y2" values="1;0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellow"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="-90" width="240" height="240" fill="url(#Gradient)"/>
  
</svg>
```

**Clarification**: I posted this answer because it's the only way (I know of) to actually rotate the direction of a gradient background without rotating the element itself. It might turn out to be useful in some edge cases where one needs the element transform for something else or they don't want to transform it.
Possible use-cases: complex container shapes (think paths) or elements which need to overflow.

As pointed out by ChrisW in the comments, IE and Edge still haven't added support for SMIL animations. However, there's a [polyfill](https://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation) for it.

That said, just because it's technically possible, it doesn't necessarily mean it should be preferred over `transform`. My gut feeling is SMIL is a bit more expensive (as far as computation goes), but I haven't conducted any tests to back this up.
Also, `transform` is less verbose, hence more practical.

Comment: @ChrisW. Browser stats: IE: 2.88%. Edge: 2.08%. I wonder how much of that is developers/website owners testing their websites in them...

Comment: In 10 years time (wishful thinking), we'll only use [WA-API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation).

Comment: Oh don't get me wrong, I ❤ me some SMIL but unfortunately I work in an enterprise shop where a large enough portion of our customers (primarily various .gov and some other other legacy folks) are forced to use IE/Edge so I've just gotten used to [the compromises](https://caniuse.com/#search=smil) of supporting the big four out of habit on everything. Sucks but thems the breaks. Though anything hitting the GPU/Compositor thread side of things for some actual multi-tier arch gets a big thumbs up from me lol.

Comment: @Chris, in all fairness, at least in this case, `transfom` is the way to go. In fact, I haven't run yet into any case that *actually* requires SMIL. And they both lack what would make complex animations a lot more useful: playback control and callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

Can you change your markup at all? If so, you could animate rotation on a separate element.

```css
.gradient-button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.gradient-button>.bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red 45%, yellow 50%, green 55%);
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

.gradient-button>.label {
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(5);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(5);
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="fill" class="gradient-button">
  <span class="bg"></span>
  <span class="label">Fill Form</span>
</a>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/oQPear)