# Animated Gradient text

Tags: css, animation, text, gradient

I am trying to animate a rotating gradient inside the text with CSS only.
The animation unfortunately doesn't animate smoothly but jumps instead.

Here is what I tried.
I would like the gradient to do a full rotation and loop.
(In the code below I tried to rotate only 180deg so you see it doesn't animate but jumps.)
Codepen: https://codepen.io/LukasJ/pen/ZEvvqYo?utm_source=pocket_mylist

HTML

```
<h1 class="gradient">Hello</h1>
```

CSS

```
html { height: 100%; }

body { 
  background: #333; 
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 { font-size: 20vw; }

.gradient {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #792eef, #fff);
  color: #000;
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
  @keyframes rotate {
     from {
      background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #792eef, #fff);
    }
    to {
      background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #792eef, #fff);
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: You can dig it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53505753/how-to-animate-more-fluently-a-rotation-of-a-background-gradient-within-element

Answer (score 1):

You have to specific more into each frame. You can't just start from 0 to 180 or to 360.

For example: I will start from 0 to 360 degree. I will use 10 frames from 0 to 100%. So, each frame will rotate 36 degree.
Here is the code.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20vw;
}
.gradient {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  color: #000;
  background-clip: text;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  10% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(36deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  20% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(72deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  30% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(108deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  40% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(144deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  50% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  60% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(216deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  70% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(252deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  80% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(288deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  90% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(324deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(360deg, #792eef, #ffffff);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="gradient">Hello</h1>
```

See it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6arxz07/).