# CSS Houdini to standard css - border animation

Tags: css-animations

Good day.

Help me refactor experimental css
[Glowing Border Animation](https://codepen.io/Mahe76/pen/PoyWvXX)
without using child html elements to standard css.
This example does not require major changes to HTML markup and the use of javascript to create wrappers

```css
@property --angle {
  syntax: "<angle>";
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
}
body {
  background: #000;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.moving-border {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #111;
  padding: 4px;
}
.moving-border::before,
.moving-border::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: -0.2rem;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--angle), 
    #032146,  #C3F2FF, #b00);
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
}
.moving-border::after {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0%     { --angle: 0deg; }
  100%   { --angle: 360deg;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="moving-border"></div>
```

thank you

Comment: What do you mean, _"without using child html elements"_? There _is_ only one single HTML element in the given example. Are you saying you want to do it without any _pseudo_ elements (the `::before` and `::after`)? If so - why? Those do not require _"major changes to HTML markup and the use of javascript to create wrappers"_ in the first place. Plus, you _will_ need some additional elements, pseudo or not - the background color of the div itself hides what is going on "beneath it", you won't be able to achieve this using just one single element that you can format, and nothing else.

Comment: In many examples https://codepen.io/tag/border-animation
structure is used

   <a href='/' class="upsale-button">
     <span>Button</span>
   </a>

[Button border animation](https://codepen.io/jeihunmammadzada/pen/qBxzJBM)
The background animation is tied to parent and child elements, their sizes, and offsets and requires significant markup changes.
There are examples with a single html element, but there is a clear binding to element size and color.
In my example, there is one html element, but many platforms do not support experimental css.

Comment: _"but there is a clear binding to element size and color"_ - colors could perhaps be handled dynamically via CSS variables (depending on what specifically you are referring to here, as problematic), and if the element sizes needs to be incorporated into the CSS for the gradient or something(?), then you'll probably have to find a way to do that.

Comment: The given example is an ideal implementation.
BUT! - **(at)property** - This is an experimental technology - The **(at)property** CSS at-rule is part of the CSS Houdini.
This technology does not work in Joomla 4, not all browsers support it.
Is it possible to translate this experimental technology into standard css?

Comment: Getting the degree portion of a linear background gradient to smoothly animate doesn't appear to be easily possible without this custom property definition (you'd have to include more steps in the keyframe) - but perhaps you can rotate the pseudo elements instead, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506093/1427878 ...?

Comment: I used such a variant.
But the entire element is animated, not its border

Comment: Don't see why that would be the case, if you still let the background color cover the actual button area. But maybe you did something different, or something wrong - impossible to tell, based on nothing but your overly vague _"I used such a variant."_ (That you would not copy&paste the example I referred to 1:1, but made modifications accordingly, was kinda implied here ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255412/discussion-between-antarey-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the background with standard CSS and standard animation, but you need to make a separate keyframe for every angle.

In the snippet, I have set 5 deg steps, so they are noticeable. You can add more keyframes to make it smoother. I have used a CSS variable, so the keyframes are easier to do.

```css
.moving-border {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(calc(var(--ang)*3.6deg), #032146,  #C3F2FF, #b00);
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  background-origin: content-box, border-box;
  animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
  border: transparent solid 10px;
}
@keyframes rotate {
 0% { --ang: 0;}
 5% { --ang: 5;}
 10% { --ang: 10;}
 15% { --ang: 15;}
 20% { --ang: 20;}
 25% { --ang: 25;}
 30% { --ang: 30;}
 35% { --ang: 35;}
 40% { --ang: 40;}
 45% { --ang: 45;}
 50% { --ang: 50;}
 55% { --ang: 55;}
 60% { --ang: 60;}
 65% { --ang: 65;}
 70% { --ang: 70;}
 75% { --ang: 75;}
 80% { --ang: 80;}
 85% { --ang: 85;}
 90% { --ang: 90;}
 95% { --ang: 95;}
 100% { --ang: 100;}
 
}
```

```html
<div class="moving-border"></div>
```